# How to scroll to anchor based on URL condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

I have some pages with content and a pagination at bottom as you can see on the picture below.

[image]

What I want to do is to (smooth) **scroll** to the anchor link if the visitor visits the second page, third page etc. (Eg. `www.example.com/list?page=2`)

I wanted to do this with a URL condition: check if the URL has "page" string then scroll to the anchor but it didn't work.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = window.location.href;
        if(url.indexOf("page") > -1) {
            scrollTop( $("#anchor-link").offset().top );
        }
    });
</script>
```

I wonder, if using a method such that (check **URL condition** with JS and scroll) or to append each pagination link with `#anchor-link` is better (performance, cross-browser etc.) and how can I do that?

Comment: `(scrollTop( $("#anchor-link").offset().top );` - seems like an extra brace?

Comment: Yes, it should be `scrollTop( $("#anchor-link").offset().top );`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a page with sections or pages named `mysection1`, `mysection2`, ...

You can get the GET parameter `page` using the function

```
function findGetParameter(parameterName) {
var result = null,
    tmp = [];
location.search
.substr(1)
    .split("&")
    .forEach(function (item) {
    tmp = item.split("=");
    if (tmp[0] === parameterName) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
});
return result;
}
```

and then, scroll to the particular section with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( '#mysection' + page ).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
var page = findGetParameter('page');

if(page == undefined)
{
   alert('No page');
   page = 1;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $( '#mysection' + page ).offset().top
        }, 500);
});



function findGetParameter(parameterName) {
    var result = null,
        tmp = [];
    location.search
    .substr(1)
        .split("&")
        .forEach(function (item) {
        tmp = item.split("=");
        if (tmp[0] === parameterName) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
    });
    return result;
}
```

```css
body { background-color: #000; color: #fff; }
a { color: aqua; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 1500px;"></div>

<div id="mysection1">Page 1</div>


<div style="height: 1500px;"></div>
    


<div id="mysection2">Page 2</div>

<div style="height: 1500px;"></div>


<div id="mysection3">Page 3</div>

<div style="height: 1500px;"></div>


<div id="mysection4">Page 4</div>

<div style="height: 1500px;"></div>
```